# If $\alpha$ is a complex root of $X^6 + X^3 + 1$, find all homomorphisms $\sigma: \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots

This is taken from Lang's Algebra book chapter 5 exercise 5

If $\alpha$ is a complex root of $X^6 + X^3 + 1$, find all homomorphisms $\sigma: \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

My (probably incorrect) solution is as follows:

Each homomorphism corresponds to an extension generated by $r, r^2, ...,r^5$ where $r$ is a root of $X^6 + X^3 + 1$. There are a total of $6$ complex roots of this equation and thus there are a total of $6$ different homomorphisms. Letting $\alpha_1, \alpha_2,...,\alpha_6$ be the roots the homomorphisms are defined as $\alpha \mapsto \alpha_i$ for $i \in [6]$.

However, I don't really buy this argument, especially the part where I claim that each homomorphism corresponds to a root. I feel lthat some similar result might be true but I'm not sure where it's stated in the book.

Comment: I suppose that the point of the exercise is that with the substitution $T=X^3$ the polynomial becomes quadratic in $T$ so that you can find the $6$ roots (hence the $6$ homs) quite explicitely.

Comment: That's the $9$th cyclotomic polynomial. Its roots are $\exp(i2\pi k/9)$ where GCD$(k,9)=1$.

Comment: Yes but what do the roots have to do with the polynomials?

Comment: Galois group is $(\Bbb Z/9\Bbb Z)^{*}=\Bbb Z_6$.

Comment: sorry, I mean what do the roots have to do with the homomorphism. but I think bob answered my question

Comment: An automorphism of $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ (or its image in $\mathbb C$) is a permutation of the roots. In this case it's raising the roots to the $k$th power where GCD$(k,9)=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all homomorphisms $\sigma: \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, we can follow these steps:

Find the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.
Find all roots of the minimal polynomial in $\mathbb{C}$.
Each homomorphism is determined by where it sends $\alpha$.
Step 1: Find the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

We are given that $\alpha$ is a complex root of the polynomial $X^6 + X^3 + 1$. To show that this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, consider the polynomial $g(X) = f(X-1) = (X-1)^6 + (X-1)^3 + 1$, where $f(X) = X^6 + X^3 + 1$. Expanding $g(X)$, we get:

$$
g(X) = X^6 - 6X^5 + 21X^4 - 42X^3 + 63X^2 - 54X + 27
$$

Applying the Eisenstein criterion to $g(X)$ with prime $p = 3$, we find that $g(X)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $g(X)$ is irreducible, it follows that $f(X) = g(X+1)$ is also irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is $X^6 + X^3 + 1$.

Step 2: Find all roots of the minimal polynomial in $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $\omega = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{9}}$. Then, the roots of the minimal polynomial are:

$$
\alpha_1 = \omega^1, \quad
\alpha_2 = \omega^2, \quad
\alpha_3 = \omega^4, \quad
\alpha_4 = \omega^5, \quad
\alpha_5 = \omega^7, \quad
\alpha_6 = \omega^8
$$

Step 3: Each homomorphism is determined by where it sends $\alpha$.

For each homomorphism $\sigma: \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, the image of $\alpha$ must be one of the roots of its minimal polynomial. So, we have 6 possible homomorphisms:

$$
\sigma_1(\alpha) = \alpha_1, \quad
\sigma_2(\alpha) = \alpha_2, \quad
\sigma_3(\alpha) = \alpha_3, \quad
\sigma_4(\alpha) = \alpha_4, \quad
\sigma_5(\alpha) = \alpha_5, \quad
\sigma_6(\alpha) = \alpha_6
$$

Therefore, there are 6 homomorphisms $\sigma: \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where each $\sigma_i(\alpha) = \alpha_i$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, 6$.

Comment: A problem in the early part. Because $3^2\mid 27$, the Eisenstein criterion does not apply to your $g(X)$. I think that you made a mistake in expanding $g(X)$, as $g(0)=f(-1)=1$ should be the constant term. It is easy to find a fix, so I'm not going to spoil it for you. Steps 2 and 3 are the key, but you may want to justify the claims because in the question the ninth roots of unity are not mentioned at all.

Comment: Can you explain why "For each homomorphism $\sigma: \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, the image of $\alpha$ must be one of the roots of its minimal polynomial"?

Comment: @Math_Day - Suppose $\sum_kc_kx^k$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, so $\sum_kc_k\alpha^k=0$. It follows that $\sigma(\sum_kc_k\alpha^k)=\sum_kc_k(\sigma\alpha)^k=\sigma0=0$.